# How to use Tensorflow to predict data type of a column in CSV?

Tags: csv, tensorflow, text-classification

I want to build a model to predict the data type of columns in a given CSV file based on pattern of data in it. My use-case is to parse the CSV file and load it into RDBMS, hence data type is very much required.

I am very new to AI/ML, but my thought is that I should be able to build a model where I can feed one or more sample data and the model will classify that into, - string, date, boolean, number etc.

While trying to google this I am seeing only articles related to data formats and loading data from CSV into Tensorflow, but not this use-case. Any pointers here will be really appreciated.

Comment: so, you want to build a model that classify if the data is `str`, `int`, `date` or `boolean`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. For example, data like `0` can mean `int`, `str` or `boolean`. When there are multiple rows and the pattern is like `0`, `1`, `0`, etc. then we can say that it is highly probable that it is `boolean`. Later I would also like to guess the date formats being used. Anyway that is another problem.

Comment: taking input shape as constant number of features, I think you should convert all to str and then use a tokenizer to replace str with numbers. Then, use positional encoding maybe to give some sense of each token and after that, using deep learning (lstm, transformers? I can't tell you which option should be better) to get an output.

Comment: There's no point using a complex ML model for this, a simple rule-based algorithm with a few regular expressions can do this very well and very efficiently. Also there are certainly libraries which do that already.

Comment: [tf.io.decode_csv](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#tfiodecode_csv) - a function for parsing lines of text into a list of CSV column tensors. Feed these tensors to model to get predictions. [tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#tfdataexperimentalcsvdataset) class provides a minimal CSV Dataset interface without the convenience features of the make_csv_dataset function: column header parsing, column type-inference, automatic shuffling, file interleaving.